# Magento 2 - Product list template not override with set template

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.0

Template doesn't set from my block.

My `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

My Block File is,

```
<?php

namespace Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('Kite_Boxes::catalog/product/list.phtml');
    }
}
```

Error occurred like,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, none given, called in /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/var/generation/Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:66 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/var/generation/Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->__construct() #1 /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(73): Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->__construct() #2 /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Kite\\Boxes\\Bloc...', Array) #3 in /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php on line 66
```

Does anyone have idea about this problem?

Comment: Do you need the block or you just want to override list.phtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue you just need to delete `generated` folder and then check.

If the cache is enabled then you need to refresh cache using

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Update your `di.xml` with this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type  name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
       <plugin name="template_of_product_list" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" type="Kite\Boxes\Plugin\ListProduct"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin `Kite/Boxes/Plugin/ListProduct.php`

```
<?php

namespace Kite\Boxes\Codepend\Plugin;

class ListProduct
{
    public function afterGetTemplate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return 'Kite_Boxes::catalog/product/list.phtml';
    }

}
```

After this you can check your productlist page.

Comment: error removed but my template is not calling

Comment: @PradipGarchar I have updated my answer for template issue. Please check.

Comment: not working template not applying

Comment: @PradipGarchar don't forget to delete `generated` the folder before you check.

Comment: @PradipGarchar have you create the file in following path `Kite/Boxes/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Comment: yes have also removed `generated` folder and template path is same as stated by you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75546/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-pradip-garchar).

Answer (score 3):

Another way, you can use do via Plugin

Create a `plugin` of class  `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

And **after** plugin method `afterGetTemplate()` of `getTemplate`.You can ***change the template file of that block class***.

**Plugin class:**

```
<?php
namespace Kite\Boxes\Plugin\Block;

class ListProductPlugin
{
    public function afterGetTemplate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result
     )
    {
        return 'Kite_Boxes::catalog/product/list.phtml';
    }

}
```

**And di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type  name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
       <plugin name="changes_template_of_product_list" sortOrder="1"  disabled="false"
       type="Kite\Boxes\Plugin\Block\ListProductPlugin"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

**Note that:**
At plugin class,you can get all public function  $subject variable.

### Most important:

- You should do di complie
- And Cache flush
- And static content deploy for active plugin

Answer (score 2):

I think you can override `list.phtml` without overriding `List.php`. If you have custom module then you need to create `catalog_category_view.xml` under layout directory

`app\code\Kite\Boxes\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml`

In this layout file, you can write

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kite_Boxes::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i want to render my listing in some conditinoal case so it won't be possible using handle

Comment: Can't you simply use xml with ifconfig for this? Or a helper function? Else a Plugin or observer would be preferable to defining a preference

Answer (score 0):

Update your block code to following ;

```
<?php
namespace Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product;
 class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {
       protected function _construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
            {
                 $this->setTemplate('Kite_Boxes::catalog/product/list.phtml');
                 parent::__construct($context);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 – Create a di.xml file in a folder Kite/Boxes/etc

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

Step 2 - The next step to overriding Magento2 block is to create a ListProduct.php Block file in the folder Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product

```
<?php

namespace Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {
        public function __construct()
            {
                echo "you can do this in block"; die();
            }
    }
```

Step3 - app/code/Kite/Boxes/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml File,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
        <!-- for magento catalog list overrider -->
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Kite_Boxes::product/list.phtml" />          
</body>
```